# Google cloud artifact registry issue when deploying GKE with terraform and helm

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-gcp

I have stored my docker images in artifacts registry in google cloud.

I have a helm chart that when I deploy with helm, everything works fine.

When I deploy with terraform, everything gets deployed. However, all images that need to be fetched from the artifacts registry fail with ImagePull errors. The configuration of these paths are done in the helm values file, so I am a bit confused why terraform fails to fetch them when I use terraform I provide my helm.tf and cluster.tf although not sure if these files are the issue.

cluster.tf

```
# google_client_config and kubernetes provider must be explicitly specified like the following.
# Retrieve an access token as the Terraform runner
data "google_client_config" "default" {}


# GKE cluster
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "my-cluster"
  project  = var.project
  location = var.region

  # We can't create a cluster with no node pool defined, but we want to only use
  # separately managed node pools. So we create the smallest possible default
  # node pool and immediately delete it.
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  networking_mode = "VPC_NATIVE"
  ip_allocation_policy {}
}

# Separately Managed Node Pool
resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_nodes" {
  project    = var.project
  name       = "${google_container_cluster.primary.name}-node-pool"
  location   = var.region
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.primary.name
  node_count = 1


  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]

    labels = {
      env = var.project
    }

    preemptible  = true
    machine_type = "e2-small"
    tags         = ["gke-node"]
    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
  }
}
```

helm.tf

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = "https://${google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"
    token                  = data.google_client_config.default.access_token
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "example" {
  name  = "test-chart"
  chart = "./helm"
  namespace="test-namespace"
  create_namespace=true

  values = [
    file("./helm/values/values-test.yaml")
  ]
  depends_on = [
    google_container_cluster.primary
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the oauth scopes of the cluster when I create it for helm, I added them to the terraform and it worked.

```
  node_config {
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
    ]
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. Where do you find a complete list of scopes available?

Comment: @JustinSoliz How I dealt with it was, I made a cluster via the console and then I checked the scopes and then copy pasted them in my tf.